# Cannot establish a connection to MySQL in NetBeans IDE

Tags: mysql, netbeans, jdbc, xampp

When I create a new web project with Hibernate, I open New Connection Wizard, choose MySQL (Connector/J driver) option (connector jar appears in the Driver Files list), I press the Next button, set Host: 127.0.0.1, Port: 3306, databasename, User Name: root, blank password field. Then I get `cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/databasename using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES))`

Here is the code from the config.inc.php file:

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

There is a couple of other config.inc.php files in XAMPP's folder (in Ubuntu), but those don't seem to contain username and password settings. There are following lines in the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file:

```
user        = mysql
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
```

So, I probably set the right port. What does this `user = mysql` mean? Why may this "cannot establish a connection"  error appear with these settings? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`user = mysql` is the OS user under which the MySQL daemon runs.  From the error message, it appears that the *MySQL* user *root* has a non-blank password.  You should determine what that password is and put it in the authentication config.

Comment: Thanks. I've just found the answer, will write in a minute. The password is actually blank.

Answer (score 0):

When I added a downloaded connector jar to the Driver Files list it worked. Somehow `/home/myname/Downloads/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar` in this list works, but the native IDE's `/home/myname/netbeans-7.0.1/ide/modules/ext/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar` doesn't.