# Netbeans won't connect to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, netbeans, netbeans-8, netbeans-8.2

I installed Netbeans IDE 8.2 on Windows 10 and disconnected MySQL 8.0 because I planned to use JDBC, without realizing that the inherent connection was already using it. I now want to reconnect, but after entering all the information into the connect pane it gives me the error "Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'.)"
[Screenshot of error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBFQZ.png)
Has anyone else had this issue and has someone figured out how to fix it?
The problem does not seem to be with a password as I entered it correctly. Netbeans is "Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot establish a connection to MySQL in NetBeans IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594494/cannot-establish-a-connection-to-mysql-in-netbeans-ide)

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate as the problem is not an authentication issue (The password is entered correctly).

Comment: Did you check these StackOverflow questions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49194719/5180017) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24081719/5180017)?

Comment: I also had this problem in NetBeans 8.2 with MySQL 8,  and fixed it by updating MySQL WorkBench to version 8.0.11rc, but [version 8.0.12](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=479196) was released today. I just upgraded to that and it is working fine, so try installing Workbench 8.0.12.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new user with standard security login.

You can use standard Type, `SHA256` Password or `caching_sha_password`.

Also, grant permissions to database that you want to access.